# Cannot launch Visual Studio Emulators (both Android and Windows Phone) - Says cannot verify digital signature

Tags: hyper-v, visual-studio-2015, vs-android, windows-phone-emulator

I'm unable to launch both the visual studio emulator for android and the window phone 8 emulator. I'm using VS2015 CTP 6.

**Windows Phone Emulator**

```
Windows Phone Emulator is unable to set the VHD on the virtual machine:

Couldn't change Virtual hard drive of the virtual machine: 'Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB.x' failed to add device 'Virtual Hard Disk'. (Virtual machine ID 60573DDO—9F9F—4002—9E40—8A46BDAADCFE)

Failed to open attachment 'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Microsoft\XDE\8.1\dd.480x800.512.vhd'. Error: ‘Windows cannot verily the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source.'.

'Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB.x': Cannot get information for attachment
'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Microsoft\XDE\8.1\dd.480x800.512.vhd'. (Virtual machine ID 60573DDO—9F9F—4002—9E40—8A46BDAADCFE)

Failed to open attachment 'c:\users\x\AppData\Local\Microsott\xDE\s.1\dd.48ox3oo.512.ylrd'. Error: ‘Windows cannot verily the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source.'.
```

**Visual Studio Emulator for Android**

```
The emulator is unable to verily that the virtual machine is running:

something happened while starting a virtual machine: 'vs — Android Phone‘ failed to start. (virtual machine ID 2481D99r—6537—4l37B—9AcAB9s27rr24srA)

'VS — Android Phone' Microsoft Emulated IDE Controller (Instance ID 83F8638B—8D(J-\—4152—9EDA—2G4\8B33039B4): Failed to Power on with Error ‘Windows cannot verily the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown
```

source.' (Ox80070241). (Virtual machine ID 2481D99P6587—4B7B—9AG4\—B9827FF248FA)

```
'vs — Android Phone‘: Failed to open attachment
'C:\Users\x\AppData\Loc.a|\Microsoft\XDE\Android\vsemulator.phone.android.vhd'. Error: ‘Windows cannot verily the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source.' (0x80070241). (Virtual machine ID 2431D99r—6537—4B7B—9AcA—B9s27rr24srA)

'vs — Android Phone': Failed to open attachment
'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Microsoft\XDE\Android\vsemulator.phone.android.vhd'. Error: ‘Windows cannot verily the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source.' (0x80070241). (Virtual machine ID 2431D99r—6537—4B7B—9AcA—B9s27rr24srA)
```

I'm not sure whether it had to do with hyper-v or not. I did a report on the visual studio installation and got the same result.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue on Windows 10, it has to do with the folder structure of the Android emulator that conflicts with the WP emulator. The "workaround" was that you can only have one installed at a time

However, you're in luck, as Microsoft has published an updated version of the Android emulator that will work side by side. Download it form here:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532868

Comment: I've reinstalled VS and I just run the update in your link. The emulator window (xde) is showing the error `The device did not responds to the connect request`. When I check hyper-v, the VM is running. Connecting to it, I get to a shell like interface. The last entry before the prompt says: `init: Failed to read from /dev/hw_random: No such device`.

Comment: Can you confirm which version of Windows you're running? There are some know issues with HyperV and inability to run SDK images on Windows 10 build 10049. You have to roll back to 10041. I've asked some people I know to look into this, please reply with that info.

Comment: I'm actually running 10041.

Comment: What about the Windows Phone emulator? I have exactly the same problem. I´ve tried setting it up as if it was a Windows Phone 8 emulator on Windows 8.1 guest, but I can´t make it work!